# How should I use SPARQL queries and semantic web?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am currently building a website which sends SPARQL queries to get information from DBpedia (mostly name of cities which can then be displayed on a map, and further information about this places like number of inhabitants, prominent persons etc).

I would like your opinion about the general use of SPARQL queries and DBpedia:

- is it preferable that I create a database specific for my website with the information that I need, and I use DBpedia queries only to update this database at regular intervals (e.g. everyday).
- or is it ok if my website sends queries systematically to DBpedia when someone comes and visit this website?

The second option is much easier for me to implement because and I don't need to worry about the extra database, 
but if everybody does the same it may surcharge the DBpedia servers?

Comment: You should also consider what DBpedia's terms of use are,and whether it's "courteous" to query often.  (For some services it could be fine, but not for others.) As others have already pointed out, DBpedia can be a bit flaky and unreliable;  are you ok with being perceived the same way (by having information unavailable when dbpedia is unavailable)?

Comment: That said, I think the question is probably a bit to broad or opinion based, and it's definitely time sensitive.  Whatever DBpedia is like today, it may not be in the future, and there's not a while lot of reason to suppose that other public endpoints will have exactly the same behaviors and policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBPedia is frequently down or unresponsive for the reasons you cite - there can be unanticipated periods of high volume on the servers.  So the first choice, caching to a local data store, is probably best.

Answer (score 1):

The *[public DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql)* which is [made available at no cost to the Web community at large](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/OnlineAccess#1.1%20Public%20SPARQL%20Endpoint) may not be suited to such use as you describe -- being the backend to what seems likely to be a freemium service of some kind.

You can instantiate your own [mirror of the DBpedia service on AWS](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtPayAsYouGoEBSBackedAMIDBpedia2015) or elsewhere, if you need a more consistently available instance.

Comment: Thanks TallTed and @Joshua for your answers regarding the respectful way of using DBpedia, this was exactly the sense of my question. TallTed, what do you mean by _not suited to such use_ isn't the first option also not an option for you?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the first option" here. I've edited my answer a bit; hopefully my meaning is clearer. You may also benefit from reading over the latest [DBpedia Usage Report](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vyzaG_p7xAXcu5ocpwcmPyy3k1xi_udFSofqIzaTMdY/edit), which gives some idea of the benefits we (I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), maker of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), the engine powering the public DBpedia endpoint) get by providing this public service.